# Wordpress on Xampp cause long ttfb

Tags: wordpress, xampp

Does anyone know why Wordpress on Xampp causes a long time to first byte, around 10-15 sec? I'm running on 100mbit box, latest Xampp and latest Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we even can help you with this, I think that more information is needed - if you are running it locally, network connection speed shouldn't matter. Maybe the specs of your machine, stuff like that.

On a slightly more helpful note (:-):

- Try running a network sniffer such as Wireshark (or using Task Manager) to check what traffic is actually going through the network - is it full?
- Is there a process taking up lots of CPU time, or thrashing the disk a lot?
- Check the speed of the MySQL database
- Try redownloading Wordpress and XAMPP, just to be sure
- Re-install Wordpress (ie, run setup.php again)
- Run the initialisation batch script for XAMPP

These are only wild suggestions, so I'm not sure how useful they will be.